# get event title and times from calendar events

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, gdata

I am trying to develop an ios app based on calendar events. I used GData to get calendar events. I am not getting how to get values of only event title and times from below calendar event output?

```
calendar events (
"GDataEntryCalendarEvent 0x175c6340: {v:2.6 **title**:Meeting at 11am. content: etag:\"GU4MQwRJeSp7JGA6WhNQ\" kind:calendar#event authors:1 categories:1 links:alternate,self,edit edited:2014-06-25T07:21:27Z id:some value visibility:event.default transparency:event.opaque eventStatus:event.confirmed **times**:(2014-06-26T00:00:00+05:30..2014-06-26T01:00:00+05:30) reminders:1 comment iCalUID:um7spasrbs3l3hgf0nnn30d7cc@google.com sequenceNumber:0 guestsCanInvite:YES guestsCanSeeGuests:YES unparsed:<gCal:videoConference>}",
"GDataEntryCalendarEvent 0x175d6e30: {v:2.6 **title**:Lunch content: etag:\"GU4MQwNCeip7JGA6WhNQ\" kind:calendar#event authors:1 categories:1 links:alternate,self,edit edited:2014-06-25T07:32:14Z id:some value visibility:event.default transparency:event.opaque eventStatus:event.confirmed **times**:(2014-06-27T13:30:00+05:30..2014-06-27T14:30:00+05:30) reminders:1 comment iCalUID:an6lhdoi12vfjtjv22k4hu69io@google.com sequenceNumber:0 guestsCanInvite:YES guestsCanSeeGuests:YES unparsed:<gCal:videoConference>}"
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for (GDataEntryCalendarEvent *event in yourEventEntries) {

    NSString *title = [[event title] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"Title : %@",title);

    NSArray *times = [event times];
    NSLog(@"times : %@",times);


    GDataDateTime *startTime = nil;
    GDataDateTime *endTime = nil;

    GDataWhen *when = nil;
    if ([times count] > 0) {
        when = [times objectAtIndex:0];
        startTime = [when startTime];
        endTime = [when endTime];
    }
}
```